# Fallout 4 saves are scrambled up in the load list xbox one...how do I fix it?

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-one

Ok so...I cant make it to lv 25 to upgrade my deliverer to its fullest potential....and it's because every new save I make vanishes to the bottom of the list or somewhere besides the top...not only that it won't show my level on all of the saves exept when you press continue (only shows what's at the top of the load list) and now I don't know which save is a recent save because everything in the load list is scrambled up...how do I fix this on fallout 4 xbox one? I've already tried scrolling and overwritting over the 1st save at the top of the load list

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me if I play offline, because the date on the Xbox is wrong. It has also happened due to daylight savings time going forward or back.

I don't think there's any way to fix the existing saves.

You could prevent it by making sure your date is correct on your Xbox.

You could replace the bad saves by loading them with the correct date/time, saving, and then deleting the bad save.

As a workaround, I recommend you look at something distinctive (preferably in third person view with your character in the shot) before saving. This will make it easier to identify the saves, even though you can't name them.

Answer (score 0):

I never just choose to continue anymore. I always select the load game option.At times my saves have been out of order. Now whenever I am about to save I try to position my character so that something somewhat memorable is onscreen.  A  screenshot  is  captured  whenever  the  game  is  saved. I use the picture to remember the location of the save. More often I look for the game time logged during the save. The save showing the most game time is my most recent save.

Comment: But is there a way to fix the issue? ..my Xbox one is somewhat slow in loading all of the saves in the load list making it hard to scroll for the right save file..it freezes up for a couple minutes then finally loads the save

Comment: My game also seems to lag momentarily when I scroll. I know of no way to guarantee that when you choose continue the correct file will be chosen. The most fool proof way, in my opinion, is choosing the save with the most game time shown. That should be your most recent game with the most progress. Just take your time scrolling through the list and delete some saves if they definitely are of no more use.

Comment: I'm getting skyrim special edition..and taking a big break from fallout 4. .at least my new vegas game doesn't do this...hopefully it won't screw up fallout new vegas to put it's DLCs in late..while it's full of like 12 different knows bugs and glitches :(